# Spring batch - executing one step back OR Re-executing previously executed steps

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job with, lets say 5 steps (`step1 --> step2 --> step3 --> step4 --> step5`) . I have configured a `StepExectutionListener`, which listens to 2 events

`beforeStep()` and `afterStep()` for all the steps.

My question is, if I am in currently `beforeStep()` method, and the step to be executed is`step2`, can I make spring-batch execute `step1` again? After executing `step1`, the flow should continue to `step2`, `step3` and so on..

To clarify again, can I tell spring-batch to "start execution" from a previously executed step again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I probably wouldn't recommend this behavior, yes, it should be able to be accomplished.  What you'll need to do is to configure step2 to have a transition to step1 with the correct exit code and step1 will need to be able to rerun.

**Configuration**

```
<step id="step1" next="step2">
    <tasklet ref="someTasklet" allow-start-if-complete="true"/>
</step>
<step id="step2">
    <tasklet ref="someOtherTasklet"/>
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="loopingListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <next on="BACK" to="step1"/>
</step>
```

**Code**

```
public class LoopingListener extends StepExecutionListenerSupport {

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        if(shouldLoop) {
            return new ExitStatus("BACK");
        } else {
            return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael Minella for your answer. Looks like a good solution. Let me try this..

Comment: @Michael Minella , how to achieve the same if we have restartable step

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a particular ordering of the steps using the following approach.

```
<step id="step1" next="step3">
<tasklet>(...)</tasklet>
</step>
```

next parameter will define which will be executed next.
However I am not sure whether you can step back in the same execution. But Spring allows you to restart a step if you use the

> allow-start-if-complete

to true.

Also for building workflows, look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/builder/FlowBuilder.SplitBuilder.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. What I want to achieve is go one step back, while the execution of the current job is in progress...  Is it anyway possible using Spring Batch API's ?

Comment: According my experience, Only option I see is using a conditional flow like <step id="step3" next="step1" on="FAILED">. for such direction.

Comment: thaks again :-) I think I understood your point. I will try the same.. Thank you.